How to cause OpenPresentation event to run in PowerPoint automatically?
I am using ActiveX combo boxes on a slide in PowerPoint.  I have a sub setup to give them options, but calling the sub is another matter.  I'm familiar with using WithEvents to allow for the events to be populated in the editor, but the way to automate the linking of a variable to the class containing the event is not obvious to me.  If I run a sub containing the link code, it works ok with any other event, but should I save and close, then reopen the deck, it does not trigger the OpenPresentation event.
clsApp Class code:
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cApp As Application

Private Sub cApp_PresentationOpen(ByVal Pres As Presentation) ' Will not run automatically.
    Call InitPres
    Debug.Print (2)
End Sub

Private Sub cApp_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Debug.Print (1)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set cApp = Application
End Sub

mCode, normal code module:
Option Explicit
Public app As New clsApp

Sub Test()
    Set app.cApp = Application
End Sub

Sub InitPres()
    Dim vCtrls As Variant, vCtrl As Variant
    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    vArr = Array("Complete", "On Track", "At Risk", "N/A")
    vCtrls = Array(Slide104.cbxTask1, Slide104.cbxTask2, Slide104.cbxTask3, _
                  Slide104.cbxTask4, Slide104.cbxTask5)

    For Each vCtrl In vCtrls
        
        vCtrl.Clear
        
        For i = 0 To UBound(vArr)
            vCtrl.AddItem vArr(i)
        Next i
        
    Next vCtrl

End Sub


If you put your code in an add-in and install it, you can use Sub AutoOpen in the add-in to run whatever code you like when PPT starts and the add-in loads.  You'd need some way to distinguish your target presentation from all others so it doesn't try to run your code on every presentation you open.

@SteveRindsberg I see, thanks for the advice.
